# How to use TouchableOpacity to hide view by in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm really new to React Native and I'm wondering how can I hide/show View
Here's my test code:

```
class Counter extends React.Component{
 state = { count:0 };
 setCount = () => this.setState(
   prevState => ({ ...prevState, count: this.state.count + 1 })
 )

 render(){
   const { count } = this.state;
   const [valueLocation, onChangeText] = React.useState('Pleas input Address');
   const [value, onChangeEvent] = React.useState('Your questions');
   return (
     <ScrollView style={styles.header}>
       <View style={styles.box1}>
         <View style={styles.box2}>
           <View style={styles.user}>
             <Image
               style={styles.userImg}
               source={{
                 uri: event.user[0].image,
               }}
             />
             <View style={styles.userText}>
               <Text style={styles.username}>{event.user[0].name}</Text>
               <Text style={styles.date}>{event.user[0].date}</Text>
         </View>
       </View>

       <View style={styles.boxHidebtn}>
         <View style={styles.EventClass}>
           <Text style={styles.btn_text_white}>類型</Text>
         </View>
         <TouchableOpacity
           style={styles.EventOpen}
           onPress={this.setCount}
         >
           <Text>></Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
     </View>
    
     <View style={count % 2 ? styles.box3 : styles.box3Open}>
       <Text style={styles.address}>台北市市民大道六段37號</Text>
       <Text style={styles.eventShow}>路上坑洞造成積水</Text>
     </View>
   </View>
 </ScrollView>
   );
 }
}

const App = () => {
 <Counter/>
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ....
});

export default App;
```

I run my code and it tell me
"App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

thanks!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) needs to return the `Counter`:

```
const App = () => {
 return <Counter/>;
};
```

Or, simply:

```
const App = () => <Counter/>;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. With your help, the code can work!!

Answer (score 0):

I can see three errors in your code:

```js
const App = () => {
 return <Counter/>; // here you should return Counter
};
```

prevState -> this.state I guess

```js
setCount = () => this.setState({ ...this.state, count: this.state.count + 1 }); // here
```

you have also a syntax error `<Text>></Text>` remove this extra closing > inside touchableopacity

Regarding your question in the title? I can't see where you want to hide the view?

Comment: It's okay, I have solved it. thank you for your help!!